# Cannot kill process in Linux: httpd -k start

Tags: linux, process, httpd, kill

I cannot kill the following process:

```
 0.0  1620 17462 /home/mertnuhoglu/webapps/django/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

I give kill command but httpd instance still runs:

```
[mertnuhoglu@web145 dj02]$ kill -9 17462
[mertnuhoglu@web145 dj02]$ ps -u mertnuhoglu -o pcpu,rss,pid,command

 0.0  3532 18479 /home/mertnuhoglu/webapps/django/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

The process id changes but the httpd instance still runs. How can I kill that httpd instance definitely?

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `-k start` tells `httpd` to restart itself if it gets killed. You have to stop the process.

```
/home/mertnuhoglu/webapps/django/apache2/bin/httpd -k stop
```

Or, if started with `apachectl`:

```
/home/mertnuhoglu/webapps/django/apache2/bin/apachectl stop
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I gave that command: "httpd -k stop" The server said: "httpd (pid 17462?) not running" and didn't stop httpd. pid 17462 was the original httpd process id above. I had killed that pid with "kill -9 17462". Is there any way to kill completely the process still?

Comment: It depends on how you've started your webserver, Try the `apachectl stop` command, i've appended it to the answer.